# Diablo 3 constant freeze lag spike, but low ping and constant FPS

Tags: diablo-iii, technical-issues

I'm sorry if tech support is outside the context of this site. If so you may close this question.

Just recently I've started getting lag spikes. I used to get this lag spike all the time but only whenever a new player joined my party game. But just recently few days ago when I started the game, the game would constantly freeze for 1-2 seconds every 15-20 seconds, and then start moving again very quickly to catch up with the things that happened during the freeze. I haven't changed my graphics card drivers, or did any hardware changes. All I did was install Path of Exile, but I'm not sure if that could have screwed up my Diablo 3. It took me quite a while to download and install updates on Path of Exile so I don't really want to try uninstalling it until I've tried other things. So far I've tried changing my graphics card settings (Catalyst 3D and Video settings), lowered everything in-game, even checked the "Low FX" checkbox. I've also tried Repairing Diablo 3 which didn't help.

I have a slow connection (2Mb) but it's enough to play the game at 65ms constant. I've used CTRL+R and didn't see any stutters in FPS when I get the lag spike. Because of my slow connection I also didn't want to re-install Diablo 3 without trying other things first.

CPU: AMD X2 7850 Black Edition stock clocking
RAM: Kingston HyperX 4GB dual channel stock clocking
GPU: ATI HD4850 512MB RAM
OS: Windows 7 64Bit

Comment: If you're on windows, check the event log to see if any errors are popping up. You should also check your networking to see if there is a connection problem.

Comment: Hi @Beebee !  Though sometimes a little controversial, technical issues are on topic, and I think you've done a good job explaining what you've tried so far which is always appreciated.  A couple of clarifying questions: 1) What is MS in this context? 2) I assume you are playing Diablo 3, even though you mention installing Path of Exile.

Comment: @EBongo yes I'm having trouble with Diablo 3. MS stands for milliseconds, in context of ping/latency.

Comment: @Beebee Given your low ping and the nature of the behavior you describe, it seems like the problem may be on your end, as opposed to a networking problem.  Can you run some type of performance monitor in the background (perfmon or similar) to check your CPU and memory performance?

Comment: @Ebongo, I had the same issue...when i did a continuous ping to Google I noticed that the connection every now and then failed. After trying everything else, i moved my pc a bit. Then the problem stopped. I think that in my case, it was related to the fact that my PC was to close to a bunch of wall sockets and that they gave interferrence of some sort.

Comment: @Sloanarc Yes, the behavior could easily be explained by intermittent high pings or dropped packets, but Beebee is saying in this case that is not happening.  I used to have a Devil of a time with several bad routers which would appear fine most of the time, and then intermittently have huge increases in ping sometimes to the point of massive packet dropping.  As you might expect, a good recipe for online gaming that does not make.

Comment: Closing as per author request.